# Internet Sharing Setting Page Launch

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to make a WP 8 which launch Internet Sharing Settings Page in Setting.
But I couldn't find out what URI to launch it. Anybody pls show me the way :)

Here example of Launch Wifi Setting URI

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-wifi:"));
```

Answer (score 1):

See [URI schemes for launching built-in apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (MSDN)

Comment: I had seen it before I posted this but I couldn't find out what I need :) tks anyway

Comment: You should then consider that it is not available.

Comment: Yeah, I think so, tks anyway :D